# Should I re-ask my question on expatriates?

Tags: support, status-completed, migration, asking-questions

My question regarding [working as a software developer in Addis Ababa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88048/where-can-a-software-developer-work-remotely-in-addis-ababa) was closed as off-topic, and the close reason stated that [Expatriates SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask.

Should I re-ask my question there (although there is currently only one question tagged Ethiopia there, a question I asked)? Should the question and answer be migrated there? Or should it be left as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general questions should not be cross-posted. If a question belongs on another SE site then it's up to the moderators to handle the migration. Honestly I am torn on this. Questions an co-working spaces are on-topic on Travel. However you are moving for 6 months and that makes your question on-topic on Expats. Let us see what the community thinks. We'll act from there.

FYI StrongBad, moderator on Expats, says he does not want this question. I asked MarkMayo too and got a similar response. The question has now been reopened. Answer away.

Answer (score 2):

IMO your question was okay since it basically asks about coworking spaces, which is on topic. Your period of stay is only tangential to the question, not an important part of it. I'd say it should be reopened.

Comment: Thank you both for informative answers. I accepted JoErNanO's answer, as he asked other moderators about this.